# why does the ofstream stream add to the second line (plain file)?

Tags: c++, string, stream, ofstream

code keeps adding my the input strings to the second line. when file is empy it adds and empty line at the top of the file and the string on the second.
(plain file not text file)

```
   string fileName;
   string fileContent;
   string fileOutput; 

   ofstream fileWrite;

    //get name
    cout << "file name: " ;
    cin >> fileName;
    cout << endl;


    //write to file
    fileWrite.open(fileName , ios::app);
    cout << "write something to file: ";
    cin >> fileOutput;
    fileWrite  << fileOutput;

    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;

    fileWrite.close();
```

Comment: If you really want line-oriented input (and you usually do), use std::getline() instead of the stream operator. You'll get better results.

Comment: @FredLarson , as in getline ( cin, fileContent ) ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. I think the stream operator is leaving the newline from the file name in the stream, and that's getting into your file content.

Comment: thanks, ill try that out. i noticed i also left out a declaration for one of the variables. adding it now

Comment: yes a solution is to relocate that endl to the "write something.." prompt doesnt really explain whats going on though , but i assume its something to do with the buffer.

Comment: the program is also not accepting adding a "getline (cin ,fileOutput);" as the input line, the program just skips the input part and program ends
compiling with g++ -std=c++

Comment: Ok, I tried actually running your code. After adding in stuff to make it actually compilable, and adding in "std::" in lots of places (because `using namespace std;` is an abomination), it worked.  Sort of. I put in "blah" for the file name and "Hello, world!" for the content. It wrote "Hello," to the file, because the stream input to string will stop at whitespace. That's why I recommend `std::getline()`. But I didn't see  blank line at the top of the file.

Comment: weird . for me it worked when i specified the stream file as .txt and another solution was moving the endl , from the file name prompt to the "write something...." prompt statement.